# Window is shown correctly even if I comment out InitializeComponent() call

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm reading Adam Nathan's book WPF 4 Unleashed and there is the following warning on page 46:

> **Don’t forget to call InitializeComponent in the constructor of your code-behind class!** If you fail to do so, your root element won’t
>   contain any of the content you defined in XAML (because the
>   corresponding BAML doesn’t get loaded), and all the fields
>   representing named object elements will be null.

I have the following code in the XAML of the main window:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow">
...
```

The code-behind file containing the MainWindow class:

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**As you can see, the InitializeComponent() call is commented out. But when I run the application my main window is loaded and shown correctly, with all the controls on it, and so on.**

**Why? I thought I would just see the empty window?**

More strangely, when I added a second window to my project:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
...

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I see the empty window when InitializeComponent() call is commented out, and the window with controls if the call to InitializeComponent() is not commented out. Why?

In case it is important, the project's target framework is 3.5.

Comment: I think you have been received an error message and you choose 'yes' to build your solution as it is have been built before?

Comment: Make sure you recompile the project

Comment: I did recompile the project, but nothing changed.

Comment: It seems to do some magic and make that call for you even if it is commented out but it is sill not a good practice.